# How to sketch Nyquist diagram of $H(z)$ by hand?

Tags: matlab, control-theory

For example, if discrete-time transfer function of the process is $H(z)=z-0.9$ and adjustment interval is $2$ time units. How to sketch Nyquist diagram of $H(z)$ by hand and not using Matlab for help? And how does changing the adjustment interval affects to the diagram? And how to calculate the angular frequency of the endpoint?

Edit:
Yes it is digital control.

Comment: Not sure but I wonder if it isn't the plot of $H(i\omega)$ in the complex plane?

Comment: Is this digital control?

Comment: Normally you would need to plot the Nyquist diagram of a continuous system with $s = j\,\omega$ from $\omega = -\infty$ to $\omega = \infty$, but for a discrete system you need $z = e^{T\,j\,\omega}$ which is periodic. So plotting from $\omega = -\pi / T$ to $\omega = \pi / T$ should be sufficient. However I do not have any experience in drawing this by hand.